# Mathematica list element sort

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I have a list, say,

```
cc = {{0.16441114380905922, 1}, {0.16441114380905922, 2},
      {-0.16441114381135857, 4}, {0.3469323902621586, 3},
      {-0.3469323902254179, 2}, {-0.26126804383825986, 3},
      {0.2612680438599802, 2}, {-0.28969854537720147, 3},
      {0.28969854538168743, 2}, {-7.968690709137364, 3},
      {7.968690708910122, 2}, {-4.000091496006696, 3},
      {4.000091495616817, 2}, {4.729024444062355, 3},
      {-4.72902444452141, 2}, {4.729024444062355, 1}}
```

I want to get the following information:

1. all the $2\times1$ sub-lists with the same first element should be
   together (e.g., {x,y} and {x,z} should be together)
2. multiplicity of the first elements

I am using `Tally` and `Sort` (also used `GatherBy`) but not much help so far.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

```
GatherBy[cc, #[[1]] &]
Length /@ GatherBy[cc, #[[1]] &]
```

Comment: `GatherBy[cc, First]` might be easier to read.

Comment: @Sasha True, but also less general; I applaud belisarius for using `Part`, though mentioning `First` is appreciated.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard hehe Glad you remember ... now I already was criticized both ways :)

Answer (score 3):

A solution using `Gather`:

```
{#, Length /@ #}& @ Gather[cc, First@#1 === First@#2 &]
```

> {{{{0.164411, 1}, {0.164411, 2}}, {{-0.164411, 4}}, {{0.346932, 
>       3}}, {{-0.346932, 2}}, {{-0.261268, 3}}, {{0.261268, 
>       2}}, {{-0.289699, 3}}, {{0.289699, 2}}, {{-7.96869, 
>       3}}, {{7.96869, 2}}, {{-4.00009, 3}}, {{4.00009, 2}}, {{4.72902, 
>       3}, {4.72902, 1}}, {{-4.72902, 2}}}, {2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
>     1, 1, 1, 2, 1}}